# how long can an app stay in developer release in itunes connection

Tags: ios, itunes

I am planning to hold an patch release for an iOS app for 4 weeks after approved by apple. Will this be a problem ? Can anyone say what is the maximum number of days for an app to be not released after approved by apple

Comment: I am not hundred percent sure, but I think it can stay as long as you want, unless your developer program expires.

Comment: Although, this question is off topic, I personally have had an app wait 1.5 months because I didn't have a computer and prior to iTunes Connect app allowing developers to do from within the app. However, this was a long time ago, so circumstances could change. The best people to ask in this scenario is Apple themselves